# Calculating a sum within an array index in Java

Tags: java, arrays, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

Solution: I was using `sum` elsewhere, and my second variation of the code doesn't update it so the issue appeared later in my code. Rather silly, and embarrassing but oh well!

This is a block of working Java code:

```java
int sum = 0;

for (int r = 0; r < k; r++) {
  sum += matrix[r][c];
}

totals[0][c] = sum;
```

`k` elements in row `r` are summed together in `sum`, which is then stored in `totals` at the appropriate index.

My question is, why can't I have my code like this?

```java
for (int r = 0; r < k; r++) {
  totals[0][c] += matrix[r][c];
}
```

Where instead of using a separate integer `sum` I simply calculate said sum in the correct index of `totals`? This produces a different and very much wrong output. Would this be a good or bad practice? For clarification `totals` is initialised to all 0 by this point.

I have a feeling that I'm missing something rather simple but I'm struggling to find any useful information on the topic, including what I've found on the nature of arrays in Java.

Comment: "*with the variables masked as to avoid recognition from my peers*" If asking here is somehow frowned upon, then why did you?

Comment: If `totals[0][c]` is initialized to 0, both snippets should produce the same output.

Comment: @Michael We are not allowed to share answers or large amounts of code, but this is a question about Java, not algorithms. With my 'relevantly' named variables the algorithm I am adapting from and the question it relates to would be rather obvious.

Comment: Fair enough. Well, Eran is right so this question is currently not reproducible. You say it gives "very much wrong output" but without further context, we cannot tell you why changing those lines changes the behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling that this may not have an answer. I don't remember ever running in to something like this and the only thing that I could think may be causing the issue may be that I'm applying the += operator to an array element directly - though I don't think this has ever been an issue for me in the past. I'm far from intermediate in Java so I thought there may be some behaviour of arrays that I'm unaware of. I think the safe bet is to check that my previously correct output truly was correct or if I'm running of a false assumption. Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: The short answer to your question is that if the position in` totals` that you are modifying is 0 when you enter the loop it will behave as you expect.  At a minimum, you should include some sample input/output where it produces right and wrong answers.  I think a problem exists in what you are not showing - how are `totals` and `c` are managed.. You could also use a debugger or print statements to monitor the calculation.

Comment: I knew it was something simple; I was using the value of 'sum' elsewhere, and in using my second version of the code I wasn't assigning the correct value to 'sum.' Quite embarrassing, really, but everything is a learning experience. I'll delete the post in a moment, as this won't really help anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

To breakdown your code:

```java
totals[0][c] += matrix[r][c];
```

means,

```java
totals[0][c] = totals[0][c] + matrix[r][c];
```

So now, consider from your very first iteration of `for` loop, you don't want to add any value previously stored in totals[0][c] right?

Now, what is the way to avoid and do the same thing in that way? just initialize to 0 before adding to it.

```java
totals[0][c] = 0;

for (int r = 0; r < k; r++) {
  totals[0][c] += matrix[r][c];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I see where you're coming from but unfortunately I have already tried that. Both in the way that you have demonstrated and also by looping through the entire totals 2D array, assigning all its values to 0. It is to my understanding that initialising any array with a given size already sets its values to 0 but I figured it was worth a shot.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem and should solve your case I mentioned if the array is initialized properly. Did you get any error btw?

Comment: No error, just an incorrect output, as in linearly less than expected. As the input grows, the output grows further incorrect. I've tested to see whether all elements of the array are in fact initialised to 0 and they are before the for loop.

Comment: As per my knowledge, I can guarantee you  if that line you mentioned in question-adding problem you want to achieve, then this is correct. If that doesn't meet your expectation, I think the problem is somewhere else, not in this code here.  Better, try some new example set of matrix, execute by pen and paper, then execute code and do cross validation with both results which and why is wrong.

Comment: Back to pen and paper it is! Though truth be told I think I may be focussing on a non-issue. My original code works so I may as well stick with it - I was mostly just curious as to whether there was some behaviour of arrays in Java that I was unaware of. Thank you for the advice, I appreciate you taking the time to reply!

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the values of `totals[0][c] = 0`.

To do this, you can do the following when creating the matrix:

```java
Float[] array = new Float[c];
Arrays.fill(array, 0f);
totals.add(array);

for (int r = 0; r < k; r++) {
  totals[0][c] += matrix[r][c];
}
```

Comment: Initialising totals[0][c] (and all of totals) to 0 unfortunately has no effect on the output. It was to my understanding that initialising an int array in Java already sets all values to 0, though. Is that incorrect?

Answer (score -1):

I was using `sum` elsewhere in my code, which I had originally read as being a new sum and not the original. As my second variation of the code was not updating `sum`, the second use of it was therefore incorrect. Silly mistake on my part, but live and learn.